# unable to to install Varnish 6.0 on AmazonLinux

Tags: varnish

I am trying to install varnish 6 image on amazon linux and ubuntu but unfortunately I am not getting successful.

I have followed both the script and manual methods at https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60/install#bash-rpm without success. See below the output. I am getting similar output on Ubuntu as well

```
[root@aaa00web32 yum.repos.d]# curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish60/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
Detected operating system as amzn/2018.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Downloading repository file: https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish60/config_file.repo?os=amzn&dist=2018&source=script
done.
Installing pygpgme to verify GPG signatures...
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                     | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
nt-local                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
varnishcache_varnish60-source/signature                                                                                                                                       |  836 B  00:00:00
varnishcache_varnish60-source/signature                                                                                                                                       |  951 B  00:00:01 !!!
(1/6): amzn-main/latest/group_gz                                                                                                                                              | 4.4 kB  00:00:00
(2/6): amzn-updates/latest/group_gz                                                                                                                                           | 4.4 kB  00:00:00
(3/6): nt-local/primary_db                                                                                                                                                    |  59 kB  00:00:00
(4/6): amzn-updates/latest/primary_db                                                                                                                                         | 351 kB  00:00:00
(5/6): amzn-updates/latest/updateinfo                                                                                                                                         | 502 kB  00:00:00
(6/6): amzn-main/latest/primary_db                                                                                                                                            | 4.0 MB  00:00:01
varnishcache_varnish60-source/primary                                                                                                                                         |  175 B  00:00:01
Package python26-pygpgme-0.3-9.12.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Installing yum-utils...
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Package yum-utils-1.1.31-40.29.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Generating yum cache for varnishcache_varnish60...

The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
[root@aaa00web32 yum.repos.d]# yum install varnish
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No package varnish available.
Error: Nothing to do

[root@aaa00web32 yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No packages marked for update
[root@aaa00web32 yum.repos.d]#
```

Anyone has any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: you mentioned ubuntu but the code block shows yum.repos.d, I assume it's amazon linux (1 or 2) .. if it's Amazon Linux 2, packagecloud script doesn't correctly detect it's rhel 7 flavour. After running script check cat /etc/yum.repos.d/varnishcache_varnish60.repo . If the baseurl shows, varnish60/el/6/$basearch change it to varnish60/el/7/$basearch

Answer (score 0):

varnish 6.0 not support amazon linux

in [https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60/install#bash-rpm][1] you could see in the install script

```sh
        else
      aws=`grep -q Amazon /etc/issue`
      if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
        dist='6'
        os='aws'
      else
        unknown_os
      fi
```

amazon linux set dist to 6

in varnish download page  [https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts?page=1][2] you can see that there is no el6

same occur if you search for el6 tag [https://packagecloud.io/app/varnishcache/varnish60/search?dist=el%2F6][3]